# Como criar uma caixa de pesquisa?

Tags: html, script

Desejo colocar em meu site uma caixa de pesquisa de **palavras** e não sei como fazer, já testei vários exemplos e nenhum funcionou!
Preciso desta caixa de pesquisa pois meu site é muito extenso e facilitaria aos usuários.

Ps.: Não vou colar meu código html aqui pois é muito extenso (8304 linhas), a não ser que seja necessário, então [aqui](https://github.com/Wigny/wigny.github.io/blob/master/cifras/cifras/index.html) está o meu código e [aqui](https://wigny.github.io/cifras/) o meu site.

Me desculpem mas sou novato e muito leigo!

Comment: A pagina é estática ? Tipo o conteudo dela vai seguir o mesmo no html ou tem alguma funcão para adicionar texto? tipo php ou javascript

Comment: Estática, se entendi a pergunta!

Comment: O que seria uma "caixa de pesquisa de palavras"? É um campo de texto que se eu digitar alguma coisa deverá acontecer o quê?

Comment: Quiz dizer como "caixa de pesquisa de palavras" como o "Ctrl + F" do navegador, que faz uma busca de palavras!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso será da forma que mencionou no comentário utilizando a mesma **API `mark.js`**, deixei as 2 respostas pois podem ajudar outras pessoas, veja na documentação que é possível fazer muita coisa. [**Documentação `mask.js`**](https://markjs.io/).

```js
$(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
   var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
mark {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  Pesquisar:
  <input type="search" placeholder="digite aqui sua pesquisa">
  <button data-search="next">&darr;</button>
  <button data-search="prev">&uarr;</button>
  <button data-search="clear">✖</button>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Quem num gosta di mé, boa gentis num é. Copo furadis é disculpa de bebadis, arcu quam euismod magna. Detraxit consequat et quo num tendi nada.</p>

<p>Viva Forevis aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent. Suco de cevadiss, é um leite divinis, qui tem lupuliz, matis, aguis e fermentis. Aenean aliquam molestie leo, vitae iaculis nisl. Todo mundo vê os porris que eu tomo, mas ninguém vê os tombis que eu levo!</p>

<p>Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose. Interagi no mé, cursus quis, vehicula ac nisi.</p>

<p>Tá deprimidis, eu conheço uma cachacis que pode alegrar sua vidis. Mauris nec dolor in eros commodo tempor. Aenean aliquam molestie leo, vitae iaculis nisl. Quem num gosta di mim que vai caçá sua turmis! Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis.</p>

<p>A ordem dos tratores não altera o pão duris. Admodum accumsan disputationi eu sit. Vide electram sadipscing et per. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi.</p>

<p>Mé faiz elementum girarzis, <a href="http://mussumipsum.com/">Site Mussum Ipsum</a> nisi eros vermeio. Nullam volutpat risus nec leo commodo, ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Diuretics paradis num copo é motivis de denguis.</p>

<p>Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Atirei o pau no gatis, per gatis num morreus. Per aumento de cachacis, eu reclamis. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum.</p>

<p>Si num tem leite então bota uma pinga aí cumpadi! Suco de cevadiss deixa as pessoas mais interessantis. Delegadis gente finis, bibendum egestas augue arcu ut est. Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Gostei do site do Mussum Ipsum, ksks!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma API jQuery para colorir em tempo de execução as palavras da busca, mas você pode adaptar este código ao seu cenário.

Importante que todo o conteúdo esteja dentro de uma `div` principal, e que o mesmo esteja em uma página estática, outro detalhe que percebi no seu código que falta um pouco de CSS para deixar o conteúdo centralizado e responsivo. Neste [link](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/web-para-dispositivos-moveis/#6-1-site-mobile-ou-mesmo-site) tem uma apostila legal para que você possa a entender os conceitos, e comece a pensar seus próximos projetos como **mobile first**.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
    // Determine o termo de pesquisa especificado
    var search = $(this).val();
    // Highlight termo de pesquisa dentro de um contexto específico
    $("#context").unmark().mark(search);
  }).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
});
```

```css
mark {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="context">
  Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Admodum accumsan disputationi eu sit. Vide electram sadipscing et per. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Nec orci ornare consequat. Praesent lacinia ultrices consectetur. Sed non ipsum felis. Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça.
</div>
```

Aqui você obtém a documentação do [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

Comment: Muito obrigado, é exatamente o que procurava!  Obrigado pela dica do css, é que sou muito leigo e minha intenção era deixar o código leve, pois ele é executado offline em um [aplicativo](https://wigny.github.io/cifras/cifras/Cifras.apk) , que foi criado pelo service worker de uma maneira inexperada, e que armazena o código em cache!

Comment: Acabei de implantar seu código no site, que por sinal funcionou perfeitamente! Só que encontrei uma nova dúvida: o código implantado destaca as palavras , mas não as "encontra". Explicando: as palavras são destacadas, mas como o texto é grande, se a palavra que procuro é uma das últimas, o documento não segue até ela, fica sempre parado no topo! Como poderei resolver esse problema? Procuro algo como o "Ctrl + F" do navegador, que ao apertar enter a palavra é "encontrada". Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Fiz minhas pesquisas e verifiquei que o que preciso se encontra em [https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/), mas quando adicionei o código em meu site o navegador me retorna erros! Poderia me ajudar editando um exemplo como fez anteriormente?

Comment: @WígnyAlmeida, ok vou verificar